# SQLite Xamarin Forms Database Table to ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite

**Hello, I'm currently trying to show a table in an Android base App. however, my question is regarding:**

```
var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Database.DatabasePath.DB_Path);
            foreach ( var N in db.Table<Database.Inventory>() )
            {

              InventoryItems.Add(new Store_Listing { Id = N.Id, 
              Description = N.Description, Style = N.Style });
```

This part of the code that is taking an error of:

> foreach statement cannor operate on variables of type 'AsyncTableQuery< ... > ' because 'AsyncTableQuery< ... >' does not contain a public instance for 'GetEnumerator'

```
foreach ( var N in db.Table<Database.Inventory>() ) "
```

I have looked into the Database.Inventory Class, and it is set to public class, and all the elements are exactly as the SQLite database (Type 3) table.

**Honestly I don't  really know what is wrong.**

There are no issues connecting the database .db3, but these error is unknown to me since I'm quite new to the SQLite and Android.App Dev.

**This is the code for the Database.Inventory:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace Inventory.Database

{
    [Table("Inventory")]
    public class Inventory

    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Style { get; set; }

    }
}
```

> Thank You for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a new instance of `SQLiteAsyncConnection`, which uses `async` instructions for all its methods (where needed). In the [SQLite NuGet source code](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), you will find that [`Table<T>`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/c360ae602dd3a36d8ffdb60e3101c872a5de872a/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L971) returns a variable of type [`AsyncTableQuery`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/b6a2febef0bec0285f3e6246e7e8bafd257bd99e/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L1111). `AsyncTableQuery` **does not implement or inherit anything**. It's a stand-alone class, which means it cannot access the method `GetEnumerator` that it is expecting to access for a `foreach` statement.

So, in your code where you have:

```cs
var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Database.DatabasePath);
foreach ( var N in db.Table<Database.Inventory>() ) // Table<T> does *not* return a List<T>!!
{
    InventoryItems.Add(new Store_Listing 
    { 
        Id = N.Id, 
        Description = N.Description, 
        Style = N.Style 
    });
}
```

You're trying to access what **you think** is a `List`, but is **actually** an `AsyncTableQuery`.

### How to get around this

If you look at the `AsyncTableQuery` class, it has a [`ToListAsync`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/b6a2febef0bec0285f3e6246e7e8bafd257bd99e/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L1203) method, which converts the `AsyncTableQuery` object to a `List<T>` object. Simply calling this will convert your `Table<T>` to a `List<T>` like so:

```cs
var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Database.DatabasePath);
var myList = await db.Table<Database.Inventory>().ToListAsync();

// TODO: Add a null or empty check to prevent NullExceptions.

foreach(var N in myList)
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = await db.Table<Database.Inventory>();

var query = conn.Table<Database.Inventory>();

query.ToListAsync().ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    foreach (var N in t.Result)
    {
      // code from your foreach loop
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details which explains what you did in order to solve OP's problem